# Need to split the value in Excel VBA into two cells

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, split

I have a fairly simple question. I just can't for the life of me figure out how to do this.

I have a range of cells in Excel like so:

```
Row  ColA
1    B001
2    B002
3    B003
4    B004
5    B005
```

I need to know how to split these cells in VBA so that they now are like so:

```
   ColB  ColC
1   B   001
2   B   002
3   B   003
4   B   004
5   B   005
```

I know you use the SPLIT command in VBA, but I'm struggling to know how to fill in the rest.  Can anyone help?

Here is a picture to help describe what I have/need in Excel

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Se8h.png)

Comment: Why don't you share the code you got so far so we can build on it?

Comment: Well the problem is it's a small part of a much larger SUB.  It would be way too confusing to post the entire code.  I was hoping the assumption could be made that my 5 example values (B001, B002, B003, B004, B005) reside in cells A1, A2, A3, A4, and A5 currently, and then how do we get those 5 values to now be split into the B letter in 1 cell and the number "001 for example" in the next column over.

Comment: What should be the final goal? To replace the values in column `A:B` with the result? Return the result in an array?

Comment: I want the values currently in cells A1, A2, A3, A4, and A5 (which are the values B001, B002, B003, B004, and B005, respectively) to be parsed and placed in the adjacent cells, like so: Cell B1 = B, Cell C1 = 001, Cell B2 = B, Cell C2 = 002, Cell B3 = B, Cell C3 = 003, and so on...up to 5. My actual problem has lots more, but this will suffice.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use Text to Columns?

Comment: Sorry yeah I realize the 2nd image above was confusing before - I've fixed it to show the final result now being in columns B and C

Comment: (eg) LEFT(A1,1) in B and RIGHT(A1,3) in c ?  Similar in VBA using Left/Mid/Right .

Comment: Well I'm trying to do it in VBA to take data already in an existing cell and parse it.  I don't think text to columns would work for that.

Comment: sorry Tim - could you expand on your answer?  what does that actually look like in a VBA script- what you were proposing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Parse Numeric Text

**Test 1**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
    
    ' If there are headers:
    'Set rg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    ReDim Preserve Data(1 To UBound(Data, 1), 1 To 2)
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        Data(r, 2) = Right(Data(r, 1), 3)
        Data(r, 1) = Left(Data(r, 1), 1)
    Next r
    
    With rg.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2)
        .Columns(2).NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = Data
    End With
    
End Sub
```

**Test 2 (without messing with the number format)**

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
    
    ' If there are headers:
    'Set rg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    rg.Offset(, 1).Value = ws.Evaluate("LEFT(" & rg.Address & ",1)")
    rg.Offset(, 2).Value = ws.Evaluate("""'"" & RIGHT(" & rg.Address & ",3)")
    
End Sub
```

**Test 3 (Using `TextToColumns` without messing with the number format)**

```
Sub Test3()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
    
    ' If there are headers:
    'Set rg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
    rg.TextToColumns Destination:=rg.Offset(, 1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(1, 2))
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

The twos (`2`) mean *As Text*, the zero (`0`) means first char (after the 0th char) and one (`1`) means after the first char.

Comment: YEP!  That's exactly what I needed. Works exactly as I requested. THANK YOU SO MUCH VBasic2008!

Comment: Thanks again.  In your Test 3 script, if you want the "001" for example to just give back a number value (i.e. "1" instead of "001"), what number do you use in your array statement in place of a "2"? UPDATE: Nevermind - I figured it out - just change it to a "1" :-)

Comment: To my understanding, the problem here was to return `001`. If you need only 1, then remove the `NumberFormat` line from the first, and `""'""&` from the second example.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, thank you so much for all the three options. Works like a charm, all these valuable knowledge helps immensely !

Comment: I think I accepted it as the answer - apologies - I'm very new to stack overflow! Let me know if I didn't acknowledge the answer correctly.

Comment: @rollsboy1979 Sir, Yup showin now, do upvote it as well!